# How to draw a line using touchesmoved+drawrect functions from one specific area to another specific area

Tags: iphone, xcode, touchesmoved

I'm working on my iPhone project about android's screen lock (similar to) application.

I have divided my view into 5 by 5 underneath each circle(3x3) and line for my created map. This is my first post so I can't post any image.

You need to drag from a circle to another circle in order to connect a line between those 2 circles.  Thus, I am using the function touches move but due to the function is keep up to the CGpoint value every time. How am I gonna keep the state for previous circle I have already drag through so I can draw a line to connect with current circle?

Answer (score 0):

use `touchesBegan:withEvent`and `touchesEnded:withEvent`. In `touchesBegan` method store your starting point and in `touchesEnded` store your end point and there you have it --> draw a line between these points.
Also make sure that the touches set passed to these function contains one touch only.

[Edit] : for continuous line drawing draw a line between your starting point and the current point received in the touch moved method

Comment: You'll also want to set the view as needing display with setNeedsDisplay

Comment: will that gonna work with an drag(touchesmoved) event as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/bunchjesse/JBSignatureController to draw the line and for specific area you can check touch point.